# How to make subqueries correct

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

Hey guys, I have some problem with subqueries in SQL. I am using MS Access 2010 and writing sql.

```
SELECT vak.Name, COUNT(vak.amount) AS [First], COUNT(vak2.amount2) AS [Second]    
FROM  
(SELECT kon.Name, (Count(icv.CV_ID) / Count(icv.CV_ID)) AS amount  
 FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.K_ID = v.K_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID  
 GROUP BY v.Vak_ID, kon.Name) AS vak,  
(SELECT kon.Name, COUNT(v.Vak_ID) AS amount2  
 FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.K_ID = v.K_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID  
 GROUP BY kon.Name) AS vak2  
GROUP BY vak.Konkursa_Nosaukums
```

When I check it in Datasheet view both columns are identical. There are 6 rows in "First" there are values 12, 12, 6, 12, 6, 6. Same values are in "Second" column. When I split this code into 2 pieces and make 2 new queries for testing, "First" Column shows values 2,2,1,2,1,1 and the second query has values of 3,3,1,2,1,1. Both of those columns have correct values when they are separately, but when I combine those, some unknown values appear like 12 (I have no idea where it take such number like 12). When I put line
WHERE vak.amount=vak2.amount2 before last line it shows 2,2,1,2,1,1 in both columns. I guess it takes only from first subquery or something.

How to make those subqueries correctly, so they show values same as when they are written separately?

Comment: Can you post sample data and individual sub queries which you have taken out ....

Comment: @Nitin Midha here are both of queries separately.
First one:
SELECT vak.Name, COUNT(vak.skaits) as [Column Name]
FROM
(SELECT kon.Name, (Count(icv.CV_ID) / Count(icv.CV_ID)) AS amount
FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.Kon_ID = v.Kon_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID
GROUP BY v.Vak_ID, kon.Name) AS vak
GROUP BY vak.Name

Second one:
SELECT kon.Name, COUNT(v.Vak_ID) AS amount2
FROM Kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.Kon_ID = v.Kon_ID
GROUP BY Kon.Name

First shows 2,2,1,2,1,1 in COUNT column,  
Second shows 3,3,1,2,1,1 in COUNT column

Comment: I think you are missing a join condition and having in apropriate group by ... Check my answer below, if it make sense ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vak.Name, vak.amount AS [First], vak2.amount2 AS [Second]
FROM  
(SELECT kon.Name, (Count(icv.CV_ID) / Count(icv.CV_ID)) AS amount  
 FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.K_ID = v.K_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID  
 GROUP BY v.Vak_ID, kon.Name) AS vak,
(SELECT kon.Name, COUNT(v.Vak_ID) AS amount2  
 FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.K_ID = v.K_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID  
 GROUP BY kon.Name) AS vak2  
WHERE vak.Name = van2.Name
```

Comment: It shows error when I did like you, removed COUNT functions and added WHERE in the end.

You tied to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'First' as part of an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a join condition and having in apropriate group by ...

```
SELECT vak.Name, vak.amount AS [First], vak2.amount2 AS [Second]
FROM  
(SELECT kon.Name, (Count(icv.CV_ID) / Count(icv.CV_ID)) AS amount  
 FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.K_ID = v.K_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID  
 GROUP BY v.Vak_ID, kon.Name) AS vak,
(SELECT kon.Name, COUNT(v.Vak_ID) AS amount2  
 FROM (kon INNER JOIN v ON kon.K_ID = v.K_ID) INNER JOIN icv ON v.Vak_ID = icv.Vak_ID  
 GROUP BY kon.Name) AS vak2  
WHERE vak.Name = van2.Name
```